# c++ time stamp to human readable datetime function

Tags: c++, timestamp

i have simple function that i need to return human readable date time from timestamp but somehow 
it returns the same timestam in seconds:

input 1356953890

```
std::string UT::timeStampToHReadble(long  timestamp)
{
    const time_t rawtime = (const time_t)timestamp;

    struct tm * dt;
    char timestr[30];
    char buffer [30];

    dt = localtime(&rawtime);
    // use any strftime format spec here
    strftime(timestr, sizeof(timestr), "%m%d%H%M%y", dt);
    sprintf(buffer,"%s", timestr);
    std::string stdBuffer(buffer);
    return stdBuffer;
}
```

output 1231133812

this is how i call it :

```
long timestamp = 1356953890L ;
std::string hreadble = UT::timeStampToHReadble(timestamp);
std::cout << hreadble << std::endl;
```

and the output is : 1231133812
and i what it to be somekind of this format : 31/1/ 2012 11:38:10 
what im missing here ?

**UTDATE :**
the solution 
strftime(timestr, sizeof(timestr), " %H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y", dt);

Comment: what is a timestamp? Is it in milliseconds or seconds?

Comment: Why do you have a temporary `buffer` and `stdBuffer` variables? The string created by `strftime` should be enough, and you should be able to just do `return timestr;`, or worst case `return std::string(timestr);`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg asked myself the same thing. Maybe he abused stringstream operator overload earlier ;-)

Comment: Can you show how you call this function, and display the result ?

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/7K2gk3. I added 6 lines to your code to create a complete program that others can run. If you had done the same then you might have an answer by now. You're probably printing the wrong thing.

Comment: i want it to be something like should be :  31/1/2012 11:38:10

Comment: Well then you need to put some `/` and `:` characters in your format string, `strftime` isn't magic, it can't read your mind.

Comment: I find that somewhat hard to believe.  `"%m"` will never output anything but a two digit number between `"01"` and `"12"`, for example; you claim it is outputting `"13"`.

Comment: @JamesKanze since there are no delimiters it could be that %m is 1 and not 13

Comment: i fixed the question im getting other result now

Comment: @claptrap `%m` always outputs two digits.

Answer (score 10):

It can be boiled down to:

```
std::string UT::timeStampToHReadble(const time_t rawtime)
{
    struct tm * dt;
    char buffer [30];
    dt = localtime(&rawtime);
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%m%d%H%M%y", dt);
    return std::string(buffer);
}
```

Changes:

- I would prefer to do the casting outside the function. It would be weird to cast a time_t to a long before calling the function, if the caller had the time_t data.
- It's not necessary to have two buffers (and therefore not necessary to copy with sprintf)

Comment: Do you mean `strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%m%d%H%M%y", dt);` on that second to last line?